# To get facebook total number of friends in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

Is there a way to directly get the total number of friends in Facebook using ASP.Net?

Using the following link we can loop and get it, but any direct way to get just the total count?

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/471668/howplustoplusgetplustotalplusnumberplusofplusFaceb

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb932386.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FQL [`user`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) table has a field called `friend_count`.